# UITableView Swipe to Delete Issue (when using separate datasource object)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem where my table view does not show the delete button on cell swipes.

I created a separate datasource class that conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. I have a `UITableViewController` that I am presenting using a `UIPopoverPresentationController`. Before presenting it, of course, I set up the datasource with all the information it needs and I ensure that it implements:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

In my `UITableViewController` subclass, I also am sure to implement both:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // do something (this doesn't get hit yet anyway, as delete button does not appear)
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be that the method `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` does not ever get called. However, if I bypass my separate datasource class and simply implement the datasource within my `UITableViewController` subclass, I notice that this method *does* get called.

I would prefer to figure out why it is the case that my using a separate datasource class gives me problems for swipe-to-delete, rather than abandoning this class (which I am using throughout my app in non-editable table views) and instead opting for keeping the datasource within the `UITableViewController` subclass entirely. Any pointers on where to look would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following tableView datasource method in your .m file.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems I had a brain fart and forgot, in practice, that this was a datasource and not a delegate method.